# How can I prevent unwanted key repeat when using PS/2 keyboard with USB adapter?

Tags: keyboards, ibm

I'm currently using an IBM Model M keyboard with a PS/2-to-USB active adapter. When I type fast on my main PC, almost any key will get "stuck" and keeps repeating until I press another key.

It also causes my mouse to stop functioning correctly. Here is the weird part. When I connect the keyboard to my laptop with the same adapter it works flawlessly. Why? Please help me fix this so I can keep typing on this lovely keyboard without issues.

Example: "Keyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyss".

Comment: Mine does this once in a while.  I suspect it is the USB-port very temporarily not supplying enough power.  Try some other ports.

Comment: I thought that might be the case. But shouldn't my laptop USB ports supply less power, than my Desktop PC?

Comment: No idea.  Does it change if you put a (n over) powered USB hub in between?

Comment: If the keyboard itself works, then the adapter is faulty. Mind mentioning which adapter you bought?

Comment: Does this also happen with another USB keyboard and your main PC?

Comment: The Model M is famously very picky about USB adaptors, I think due to being at the extreme re: voltages.

Comment: It does not happen with another USB keyboard. The adapter works fine on my laptop so the issue must be with my Desktop USB ports. Fyi it happens on all of the ports.. oh and I haven’t tried a powered hub yet.

Comment: So if it works on another PC, then it's basically fault/feature of that PC combined with the adapter being used with the keyboard. The fault is likely not in the retro keyboard itself, so if this is about modern adapter not working with a modern PC, this may not be on-topic.

Comment: @JoachimE I’m not sure that’s a valid conclusion; it could be that the Model M is marginally outside of spec with regards to something, which happens to be within tolerance for the laptop+adaptor but not for the desktop+adaptor.

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. I got a third adapter/converter and that did the trick. It was even cheaper then the first two I purchased but works like a charm.

Comment: Please make this an actual answer, if you think this is retrocomputing. However, since it seems to be an issue of a modern adapter working with a modern PC, you might want to delete the question. Just don't let it open, please. This is not a forum.